# Mate, dual screen, Windows list not displaying second screen apps

Tags: multiple-monitors, workspaces, mate

I have a dual screen working properly on my laptop with Ubuntu 15.10 and Mate.

The problem is that the "Windows list" in my panel is not showing names of windows displayed on the second screen.
I know that I can configure the "Windows List Preferences" to show windows from all workspace, but there is no link. This is the same workspace, just another screen...

Answer (score 2):

It is not a perfect solution, but I found this on another forum and it works for me.  Create a new panel on the 2nd screen (Right click the panel and select New Panel then uncheck the expand box.  You can then drag the panel to the 2nd monitor.)  and another Windows List to the new panel and it will display the windows on the screen.

Comment: Hi @Thatsafinecigar, Thanks for your reply. Since 2015, I have changed my distribution and windows manager. I'm now running 16.10 with Cinnamon. By the way, thank you for contributing. Cheers. Olivier.

Comment: @Thatsafinecigar Do you perhaps know how to make MATE alt+tab to work only for one minitor as well? Right now I struggle to figure out how to make alt+tab to switch windows from current monitor instead of whole workspace.